# Variable two options

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, var

Had a look around and couldn't find anything that solved this very simple problem.

I'm still learning jQuery so prior apologies for my stupidity on this one, I know it's a very simple fix but things like using `||` and trying to using `if` and `else` inside a `var` don't see to work for me.

Essentially this is what I have currently.  All I want is to add/remove the class "whitebg" depending on the scroll position and height of the element, which works well.

The problem is trying to query two different elements that each need a different height buffer as you can see (-167 and -90) so cannot be grouped, but need to be 'either / or' so both are accounted for.

Many thanks

Rb

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      Menuresize();
});

function Menuresize() {

    var myheight = jQuery(".section-image-slider, .section-video-slider").height() - 90;

    var myheightalt = jQuery(".area-tag").height() - 167;

    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > myheight) {
        jQuery(".bt-menu").addClass("whitebg");
    }
    elseif (scroll > myheightalt){
        jQuery(".bt-menu").addClass("whitebg");
    }
    else {jQuery(".bt-menu").removeClass("whitebg");}
};

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    Menuresize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) can take a boolean parameter to toggle on/off the class specified. You can then work out a compound boolean expression that results in `true` or `false`:

e.g.

```
 jQuery(".bt-menu").toggleClass("whitebg", scroll > myheight || scroll > myheightAlt);
```

*I found the question a little hard to follow so, if it is something else you wanted, please clarify :)*

Comment: Will try this thanks TBA, remember you were really helpful last time :) Yes you are bang on with your assumption, struggling to get this to work unless I am being stupid.  If you are able, please demonstrate that in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zwsx7k0x/1/

Comment: The numbers that get logged for `myheight` and `scroll` are not usable http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zwsx7k0x/2/ Can you explain *simply* what the overall aim is again? As in "when I do blah it shows blah" etc :)

Comment: Sorry dude. So essentially just toggle the class on the bt-menu div when the menu button top left exceeds the top section - it's height.  Updated my fiddle to show why, as the menu button would loose clarity when it leaves the section : http://jsfiddle.net/zwsx7k0x/3/

Comment: Ah ok, I think I've confused you. It's triggered OnScroll, so when the scroll position > the height of the first div - menu button height, it add class "whitebg".  That class is removed if scroll position is less than the height, so when you're scrolling on top of the first div.  This works perfectly currently, but I can't get it working with different first divs at the same time as my pages have two different types of first divs.  That fiddle says it best, the grey menu button should change when it overlaps the edge of the div.

Comment: Okay. There appear to be several things missing from your JSFiddle. I changed the styling as .whitebg was not overriding the ID match style and made it solid white for now. Please add any additional sections (like `area-tag`) to this new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zwsx7k0x/4/.

Comment: That's bob on mate, thanks so much for that.  All I had to add seemingly to get it to work was a conditional on the `.resize` and `.scroll` functions at the bottom, to 'check' which div was present and apply accordingly.  `.area-tag` can be substituted for `.section-image-slider` as it's an either or based on which page is loaded. Demo'ed here : http://jsfiddle.net/zwsx7k0x/5/ uncomment the section to test, and comment out the other.  This is working great for me now. Oddly I couldn't set the selector as the same class as the `hasClass`, it had to be a different one on my site but works here ^

Comment: user4329628: Note if you wrap your code in a shortcut DOM ready handler like `JQuery(function($){YOUR CODE HERE});` you can use the standard `$` for jQuery without fear of clashing (and much shorter).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next time!  Wordpress got me off on the wrong foot as I used to try $ instead of jQuery but that obviously clashes, but using a shortcut makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `Menuresize` function take parameters for the selectors and height, and then just call it for each:

```
function Menuresize(selector, height) {

    var myheight = jQuery(selector).height() - height;

    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > myheight) {
        jQuery(".bt-menu").addClass("whitebg");
    }
    else {
        jQuery(".bt-menu").removeClass("whitebg");
    }
};

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    Menuresize(".section-image-slider, .section-video-slider", 90);
    Menuresize(".area-tag", 167);
});
```

Comment: thanks dude, just trying to create it on here http://jsfiddle.net/zwsx7k0x/ to test these ideas, seem good :)

Comment: I was a little hasty the first time and left in a reference to myheightalt in the new function.  Should be better now.

Comment: Ideal thanks mate.  Still struggling with this in the fiddle though unless I'm being stupid http://jsfiddle.net/zwsx7k0x/1/